# Permissions of /boot/grub/menu according to security tool "tiger"

Tags: grub2, security

Open-source security tool "tiger" sent me an email containg  this:

`The configuration file /boot/grub/menu.lst has world permissions. Should be 0600`

This is reported twice, once as a warning and in the same mail on the next line, as a failure.

Now I have two questions:

- Should I set permissions as the tool recommends? (This is for a fileserver exposing only very few ports, but to the general internet)
- Is this a misconfiguration of the tool (because it occurs twice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Executive Summary:**

You should change the file permission to be `600`

```
chmod 600 /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

You might want to do the same for `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

---

**Detailed Answer:**

This issue was reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/248843) a long time ago

```
tiger emits these two notices:
# --WARN-- [boot02] The configuration file /boot/grub/menu.lst has group permissions. Should be 0600
# --FAIL-- [boot02] The configuration file /boot/grub/menu.lst has world permissions. Should be 0600
```

> I see no reason to worry about it having root group access. This should be fixed in tiger.
>
> menu.lst should not be world-readable to protect the (optional) password hash there-in from dictionary cracking attempts. This should be fixed in grub.

According to the link in `launchpad` `grub2` was fixed.

Comment: I'll change it to 0600 just to harden the server a bit more, I'll accept the "annoyances" as mentioned in the Launchpad bugreport.

Comment: this may be a bit late but changing the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` permission won't work as `update-grub` command will simply reset it to 444